# Mailing with swiftmail cannot send a link <a>

Tags: php, html, email, hyperlink

I have an issue when sending mail through php. Including a link is giving me strange results.. I get the emails with the link working correctly unless I try and put / in it. For example, emailing

```
<a href='http://example.com'>Link!</a>
```

works fine but when I change that to

```
<a href='http://example.com/info'>Link!</a>
```

it no longer works.

I originally tried using the regular mail() method and have now also tried SwiftMail but the problem is still there.

Any one know what the deal is here?

Comment: When you say doesn't work, what does it do or not do specifically?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I just don't get the mail.. not sure how to troubleshoot other than whats above :/